# Unable to update Excel sheet in TestComplete via JScript

Tags: excel, adodb, jscript, testcomplete

I am unable to update a .xlsx sheet in TestComplete via JScript since I get the following error "No value given for one or more required parameters."

```
connStr = Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\TestComplete 9 Projects\AWS-R Project Suite\TestData\TS_003.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;ReadOnly=False;HDR=Yes;"

sSQLQuery = UPDATE [TC_PlaceVectorOrder_001$] SET [Result] = Pass where [No] = 1; 

objConn = Sys.OleObject("ADODB.Connection");
objConn.Open(connStr); 
recset = objConn.Execute(sSQLQuery);     ///this line throws the exception

objConn.Close();
```

Comment: As the exception states `No value given for one or more required parameters. ` you are missing a parameter

Answer (score 2):

The string literal in

```
sSQLQuery = UPDATE [TC_PlaceVectorOrder_001$] SET [Result] = Pass where [No] = 1;
```

must be quoted:

```
sSQLQuery = "UPDATE [TC_PlaceVectorOrder_001$] SET [Result] = Pass where [No] = 1";
```

Then it's obious that "Pass" is meant either as a literal string/varchar value or a variable containing the value to be stored. In the first case, try

```
sSQLQuery = "UPDATE [TC_PlaceVectorOrder_001$] SET [Result] = 'Pass' where [No] = 1";
```

in the second, try

```
sSQLQuery = "UPDATE [TC_PlaceVectorOrder_001$] SET [Result] = '" + Pass + "' where [No] = 1";
```

An UPDATE query should not return a resultset; so just execute:

```
objConn.Execute(sSQLQuery);
```